# Надо ли создавать отдельный репозиторий для резюме?

Tags: python

Подскажите, если я в резюме на hh хочу ссылку на свой гитхаб дать, то как лучше сделать, создать отдельный репозиторий с теми проектами, которые я хочу показать? Не страшно, что будет видно, что он 2 дня назад создан? Или лучше дать ссылку на весь мой основной репозиторий, где все в кучу свалено?

Comment: мне кажется, что если вы в резюме добавляете ссылки и т.п., то ценность резюме от этого только снижается или вы думаете, что крупный работодатель будет какие-то проекты рассматривать перед тем как на собеседование пригласить?

Comment: Ну да, я думал, что если устраиваешься разработчиком, даже и джуном, то не лишним будет указать ссылку на свои пет-проекты, чтобы могли посмотреть на мой код.

Comment: ну вы поставьте себя на место работодателя - отдел кадров в программировании не понимает, он по другим критериям выбирает, а непосредственному будущему руководителю, которому и нужен сотрудник, время смотреть его код (а таких кандидатов и несколько десятков может быть) на просмотр кода нет времени совершенно!!! Поэтому в резюме и пишут 1) навыки 2) опыт работы 3) созданные проекты (если они значимые, коммерческие, а не просто поделки для друзей), размещать какие-то ссылки на свои поделки - плохой тон. Так что поставьте себя на место работодателя и все поймете

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, лучше почисти репозиторий и оставь только проекты, за которые тебе меньше всего стыдно. Или же новый, на твой выбор. Главное никак давно он создан, а какие проекты ты на него зальёшь. Удачи, в поиске первой работы.

upd:
Есть ещё возможность скрывать проекты, но там только за деньги. Думаю, такой вариант тебя меньше всего устраивает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и пожелание, я почему спрашивал, не критично ли, что репозиторий создан недавно, т.к. где-то в инете видел, что смотрят, как часто я делаю коммиты, т.е. я так понимаю, чтобы не было сомнений, что код мой, а не то, что я взял откуда-то чужой код, скопировал к себе и создал новый репозиторий. Ну в любом случай мой код, как джуна наверняка ужасный, поэтому  всем и так будет понятно, что он мой =)

Comment: Не вижу особого смысла смотреть у джуна коммиты, если и так понятно, что он работает в соло и опыта совместной разработки - не было. В случае Джуна, лично по моему опыту гитхаб нужен, чтобы глянуть его код. Чтобы посмотреть, стоит ли вообще звать на собеседование. На собеседование всё станет ясно, вы делали или не вы.

Comment: Поверьте, гитхаб это лишь часть на что смотрит работодатель. Так же резюме должно быть оформлено кратко и понятно, без всякой воды. Ещё раз удачи в ваших начинаниях. Главное не сдавайтесь. Программирование - это марафон. Главное пройти дистанцию, а судя по Вам. Вы уже близки к позиции Джуниор. Дело осталось за малым.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд лучше создать отдельный проект, в котором сделать хорошее `readme.md`, написать там свои умения, кратко описать свои проекты, которыми вы гордитесь, и дать на них ссылки. То есть чтобы как бы была отдельная "точка входа" именно для работодателей, чтобы можно было быстро оценить ваши умения.

Но вообще в идеале, конечно, и у всех ваших проектов должны быть нормальные `readme` файлы.